# How can i compare two strings for same value using joi library

Tags: node.js, joi

I have write the code for forget password then i want to validate password and retype password for the same using joi library. How can i do that.
I have write this code but it is throwing error joi.string.valid is not a function.

Here i'm using joi library as

```
 const schema=joi.object({
  pass:joi.string().required().label('Please Fill Password'),
 password:joi.string().min(8).required().label('Password must be 8 characters long'),
  pass2:joi.string().required().label('Please Re-enter Password'),

  password2:joi.string.valid(joi.ref('password')).label('passwords don\'t match'),

  })
  let result=schema.validate({pass:pass,password:pass,pass2:pass2,password2:pass2});
  if(result.error){
      console.log('fd'+result.error);
      response.send(result.error.details[0].context.label);    
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your code. You forgot the `()` on `string()` on property `password2`

```js
// missing ()
password2:joi.string.valid(joi.ref('password')).label('passwords don\'t match')
// added () 
password2:joi.string().valid(joi.ref('password')).label('passwords don\'t match')
```

Comment: There is no such a option with joi.string().valid ....